# Configuring Android to IP FORWARDING

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, iptables

Android version : Lollipop. Rooted: Yes.

I'm trying to connect a PC to a Laptop via a WLAN.

I'm using my android as a WifiAdapter. I connected the android node to the WLAN. With a USB cable connected to the PC, and enable tethering.

So it's something like this : PC -- USB Cable --> Android --> (( WLAN )) <-- Laptop

Also enable ip-forwarding on the android

```
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forwarding
```

Laptop replied to an echo message from PC:

```
    PC$ ping LAPTOP_IP -n 1
    32 bytes from LAPTOP_IP: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=14.0 ms
```

I can start a connection on port 22 from Android to Laptop (using telnet because I currently don't have a ssh-client installed on the Android).

```
    1|root@osprey_umts:/ # telnet LAPTOP_IP
    SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u2
```

But I can't start a connection to the Laptop from the PC throught that port.

On the laptop I have no iptables-rule:

```
    root@laptop$ iptables -nvl
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 742 packets, 60749 bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 606 packets, 360K bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

And on the android I did clean all the rules (including the nat table)

```
    iptables -F
    iptables -F -t nat
```

I can't make it work

```
    PC$ telnet LAPTOP_IP 8080
    Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Comment: What about firewall on your PC? Is there an outward rule blocking the remote ip 8080?

Comment: Thought that might be, but disabled the Firewall of Windows 7 (PC)

Comment: Since you say, *"Laptop replied to an echo message from PC:"*, its obvious that the laptop could be reached from the PC, its only a matter of opening the firewall ports in between. If you have cleared the firewalls of all three devices, that just couldn't be true! If the firewalls are open the connection has to pass through because the ping is passing through. Check the firewalls again, especially the Advanced Settings in Windows7 - There are usually rules defined to allow/block separate programs/ports plus there is a blanket rule to accept/deny ALL in/out connections....

Comment: ... depending on your network type: Public or Private networks.

Comment: Went to advanced settings, and disabled all rules (out / in). Still having trouble.

Comment: Is there another way to accomplish this without the firewall-configuration on the android??

Comment: Just disabling the in/out rules in windows is not enough I am adraid. You have to also set the default in/out policy for the public and private groups(it is somewhere in that same area, search and you will find it).

Comment: The policy for outgoing connectins is to **allow**. And that makes sense because I can start a connection on any port to any other host that isn't behind the android device, I mean every connection that doesn't go to the route associated with the android device.

Comment: In that case, the only thing I could think of is some built-in restriction in your Android's linux kernel that your OEM might have put. Can you try this same setup with some other android tablet/phone?